# Javascript Copy Function - This should work but isn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok I have done this a million times. This is frustrating I cannot for the life of me figure out why this isn't copying my content from (notefield) I need a fresh pair of eyes to call me a dummy....

It's hit or miss it will work on 1 attempt then not again for 20 more tries. I have a feeling it has to do with something I am doing that I am overlooking.

my CopyReset() function is just failing 90% of the time and I have made this function 10000 times before no issue...

HTML (With copy function)

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Tech Helper </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\layout.css">
<script src="scripts\newTicket.js"></script>
</head>
<header> 
<div id='header' class='header'>
<div id='logo' class='logo' align='right'> 
<img src="redactedlink" class='banner'></img>
</div> 
<div class='headtable'>
<table id='headtable'>
<tr>
<th>Technician Name: <input type="text" id='techName' value=""> </th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</header>
<body onload="LoadScript()">

<div id='container' class='container'> 
<table id='containertable' class='tabcontainer'>
<tr>
<td class='tableft'><div id='navmenu'></div></td>
<td class='tabright'><table id='content'></table></th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
<div id='footer' class='footer'> 
<table id='foottable' class='foottable'>
<tr>
<th> Footer </th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<textarea id="notefield" class="hiddentext"></textarea>

<script> 

function CopyReset() { 
var target = document.getElementById('notefield');
target.select();
document.execCommand('copy');

//alert("Cancellation Notes Copied");
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "";
//document.getElementById("notefield").value = "";
}

</script>
</html>
```

Javascript newTicket.js

```
function LoadScript() { 
document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "<input type='button' onclick='NewTicket()' 
class='navButton' value='New Ticket' id='newTicket'>";
}

var reached = "false";
function NewTicket() { 
var incident = prompt("Enter Incident Number");
var c =  document.getElementById("content");

if ( incident == null || incident.length != 15 ) { 
alert("Invalid Incident Number Entered, Please enter a valid Incident number!");
}
else if ( incident != null && incident.length == 15 ) { 
c.innerHTML = "<tr> <td colspan='100%'> Incident: <input type='text' id='incField' value='' 
class='readonlyfield' readonly></td></td>";
c.innerHTML += "<tr id='contactInfo1'> <th colspan='2'>Please Select Contact Method:</th></tr><tr 
id='contactInfo2'><td colspan='2 class='td1'><div id='contactInfo' align='center'> Phone: <input 
type='radio' onclick='phoneContact()' name='contactType' id='phone'> Skype: <input type='radio' 
onclick='skypeContact()' name='contactType' id='skype'></div></td></tr>";
document.getElementById('incField').value = incident;
document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "<input type='button' class='navButton' value='Cancel 
Ticket' onclick='CancelTicket()' id='endTicket'>";
 
}


}


function phoneContact() {
var numberUsed = prompt('Please Enter the number you called the user at');
if ( numberUsed == null ) {
alert('Must enter a Phone Number');
}
else if (numberUsed != null) { 
document.getElementById('notefield').value += "Reached user at: " + numberUsed + "\n"; 
reached = "true";
document.getElementById('contactInfo1').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('contactInfo2').innerHTML = "";
}

} 

function skypeContact() {
var skypeLog = prompt('Please Contact Log to begin');
if ( skypeLog == null ) {
alert('Must Provide Contact Log!');
}
else if (skypeLog != null) { 
document.getElementById('notefield').value += "Reached User via Skype: " + skypeLog + "\n"; 
reached = "true";
document.getElementById('contactInfo1').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('contactInfo2').innerHTML = "";

}

} 


function CancelTicket() { 
    if (reached == "false" ) { 
        alert('Canno Cancel Ticket Without Contact');
    }
    else if (reached == "true" ) {
        var reason = prompt("Reason for cancelling ticket: ");
                if (reason == null) {
            alert('Cancel Reason cannot be blank!');
            }
            else if (reason != null) {
                document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "<input type='button' 
class='navButton' 
onclick='NewTicket()' value='New Ticket' id='newTicket'>";
                document.getElementById('notefield').value += "Ticket Cancelled, Reason: " + reason;
                CopyReset();
        }
    }
}
```

And for SNG's CSS layout.css

```
.header {
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
background-color:blue;
width: auto;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top:20px;
height: 80px;
position:relative;
}
.headtable { 
position:absolute;
margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
.logo { 
width:350px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-right:10px;
float:right;
}
.td1 { 
text-align: right;
}
.banner { 
}
.hiddentext {
opacity:100%;
}
.incbox {
float:left;
}
.readonlyfield { 
background-color: #eee;
}

.navButton { 
width: 100%;
height:25px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-color:blue;
}
.navButton:Hover { 
border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
border-color:black;
background:lightblue;
opacity: 96%;
}


.container {
background-color:green;
width: auto;
height: 600px;
position:relative;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}

.tabcontainer {
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
}
.tableft {
vertical-align: text-top;
background-color: yellow;
width:15%;;

}
.tabright {
vertical-align: text-top;
background-color: pink;
}

.footer {
position:relative;
border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
bottom: 0px;
background-color:red;
width: auto;
height: 80px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please create an example on JSBin or CodePen, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here I've bug fixed a little your JS code, especially some line breaks within single quotes where some html tags is placed... Also added block to run JS only after DOM loaded, don't know is it the case, but in sandbox here it gives error without it. So check demo below, in my case text pasted to `textarea` and copied to clipboard when you cancel ticket

```js
function LoadScript() { 
document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "<input type='button' onclick='NewTicket()' class='navButton' value='New Ticket' id='newTicket'>";
}

var reached = "false";
function NewTicket() { 
var incident = prompt("Enter Incident Number");
var c =  document.getElementById("content");

if ( incident == null || incident.length != 15 ) { 
alert("Invalid Incident Number Entered, Please enter a valid Incident number!");
}
else if ( incident != null && incident.length == 15 ) { 
c.innerHTML = "<tr> <td colspan='100%'> Incident: <input type='text' id='incField' value='' class='readonlyfield' readonly></td></td>";
c.innerHTML += "<tr id='contactInfo1'> <th colspan='2'>Please Select Contact Method:</th></tr><tr id='contactInfo2'><td colspan='2 class='td1'><div id='contactInfo' align='center'> Phone: <input type='radio' onclick='phoneContact()' name='contactType' id='phone'> Skype: <input type='radio' onclick='skypeContact()' name='contactType' id='skype'></div></td></tr>";
document.getElementById('incField').value = incident;
document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "<input type='button' class='navButton' value='Cancel Ticket' onclick='CancelTicket()' id='endTicket'>";
 
}


}


function phoneContact() {
var numberUsed = prompt('Please Enter the number you called the user at');
if ( numberUsed == null ) {
alert('Must enter a Phone Number');
}
else if (numberUsed != null) { 
document.getElementById('notefield').value += "Reached user at: " + numberUsed + "\n"; 
reached = "true";
document.getElementById('contactInfo1').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('contactInfo2').innerHTML = "";
}

} 

function skypeContact() {
var skypeLog = prompt('Please Contact Log to begin');
if ( skypeLog == null ) {
alert('Must Provide Contact Log!');
}
else if (skypeLog != null) { 
document.getElementById('notefield').value += "Reached User via Skype: " + skypeLog + "\n"; 
reached = "true";
document.getElementById('contactInfo1').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('contactInfo2').innerHTML = "";

}

} 


function CancelTicket() { 
    if (reached == "false" ) { 
        alert('Canno Cancel Ticket Without Contact');
    }
    else if (reached == "true" ) {
        var reason = prompt("Reason for cancelling ticket: ");
                if (reason == null) {
            alert('Cancel Reason cannot be blank!');
            }
            else if (reason != null) {
                document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "<input type='button' class='navButton' onclick='NewTicket()' value='New Ticket' id='newTicket'>";
                document.getElementById('notefield').value += "Ticket Cancelled, Reason: " + reason;
                CopyReset();
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.header {
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
background-color:blue;
width: auto;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top:20px;
height: 80px;
position:relative;
}
.headtable { 
position:absolute;
margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
.logo { 
width:350px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-right:10px;
float:right;
}
.td1 { 
text-align: right;
}
.banner { 
}
.hiddentext {
opacity:100%;
}
.incbox {
float:left;
}
.readonlyfield { 
background-color: #eee;
}

.navButton { 
width: 100%;
height:25px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-color:blue;
}
.navButton:Hover { 
border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
border-color:black;
background:lightblue;
opacity: 96%;
}


.container {
background-color:green;
width: auto;
height: 600px;
position:relative;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}

.tabcontainer {
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
}
.tableft {
vertical-align: text-top;
background-color: yellow;
width:15%;;

}
.tabright {
vertical-align: text-top;
background-color: pink;
}

.footer {
position:relative;
border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
bottom: 0px;
background-color:red;
width: auto;
height: 80px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Tech Helper </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\layout.css">
<script src="scripts\newTicket.js"></script>
</head>
<header> 
<div id='header' class='header'>
<div id='logo' class='logo' align='right'> 
<img src="redactedlink" class='banner'></img>
</div> 
<div class='headtable'>
<table id='headtable'>
<tr>
<th>Technician Name: <input type="text" id='techName' value=""> </th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</header>
<body onload="">

<div id='container' class='container'> 
<table id='containertable' class='tabcontainer'>
<tr>
<td class='tableft'><div id='navmenu'></div></td>
<td class='tabright'><table id='content'></table></th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
<div id='footer' class='footer'> 
<table id='foottable' class='foottable'>
<tr>
<th> Footer </th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<textarea id="notefield" class="hiddentext"></textarea>

<script> 

function CopyReset() { 
var target = document.getElementById('notefield');
target.select();
document.execCommand('copy');

//alert("Cancellation Notes Copied");
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "";
//document.getElementById("notefield").value = "";
}

// Wait for DOM loads
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  LoadScript()
});

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: so @tarkh sadly I am experiencing the same issue, it will copy sometimes but not every time. I think it has to do with the button being added via javascript I will attempt it with a static button and see what happens.

Comment: well, can't reproduce in Safari 13 on macOS

Comment: issue is on Chrome on Win 10. It' wasn't copying correctly also I managed to debug it a little further and removed some code from my if statements on my Cancel function apparently the function was causing the issue with it not copying. It copied 1 out of maybe 20 times. now I have it working every singe time.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out without removing the buttons

newTicet.js

```
function LoadScript() {
    document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "<input type='button' onclick='NewTicket()' class = 'navButton'value = 'New Ticket'id = 'newTicket' > ";
}
reached = 0;
function NewTicket() {
    var incident = prompt("Enter Incident Number");
    var c = document.getElementById("content");
if (incident == null || incident.length != 15) {
    alert("Invalid Incident Number Entered, Please enter a valid Incident number!");
} 
else if (incident != null && incident.length == 15) {
    c.innerHTML = "<tr> <td colspan='100%'> Incident: <input type='text' id='incField' value='' class = 'readonlyfield' readonly> </td></td> ";
    c.innerHTML += "<tr id='contactInfo1'> <th colspan='2'>Please Select Contact Method:</th></tr><tr id='contactInfo2'> <td colspan = '2 class='td1'><div id='contactInfo' align='center'> Phone: <input type='radio' onclick='phoneContact()' name='contactType'id = 'phone' > Skype: <input type='radio' onclick = 'skypeContact()' name = 'contactType' id = 'skype' > </div></td > </tr>";
    document.getElementById('incField').value = incident;
    document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "<input type='button' class='navButton' value='Cancel Ticket' onclick='CancelTicket()' id='endTicket'>";
    }
}
function phoneContact() {
    var numberUsed = prompt('Please Enter the number you called the user at');
    if (numberUsed == null) {
         alert('Must enter a Phone Number');
} 
else if (numberUsed != null) {
        document.getElementById('notefield').value += "Reached user at: " + numberUsed + "\n";
        reached = 1;
        document.getElementById('contactInfo1').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('contactInfo2').innerHTML = "";
    } 
}

function skypeContact() {
    var skypeLog = prompt('Please Contact Log to begin');
    if (skypeLog == null) {
        alert('Must Provide Contact Log!');
} 
else if (skypeLog != null) {
        document.getElementById('notefield').value += "Reached User via Skype: " + skypeLog + "\n";
        reached = 1;
        document.getElementById('contactInfo1').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('contactInfo2').innerHTML = "";
    }
 }

function CancelTicket() {
    if (Boolean(reached) == false) {
    alert("Cannot Cancel Ticket Without Contact");
} 
 else if (Boolean(reached) == true) {
       var reason = prompt("Reason for cancelling ticket: ");
  } 
if (reason == null) {
    alert("Cancel Reason cannot be blank!");
  }
     else if (reason != null) {
            document.getElementById('navmenu').innerHTML = "<input type='button' class='navButton' onclick='NewTicket()' value='New Ticket' id='newTicket'>";
        document.getElementById('notefield').value += "Ticket Cancelled, Reason: " + reason;
    CopyReset();
    }
}
function CopyReset() {
var target = document.getElementById('notefield');
target.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
alert("Cancellation Notes Copied");
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("notefield").value = "";
}
```